# "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

On my pc, i have the following:

- IDE: VS2008
- O/S: Windows XP

When I create a new web application and add a new webform, i get the following error:

> "Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt."

The following files should get created:

1. .aspx
2. .aspx.cs
3. .aspx.designer.cs

However, the last file (3) .aspx.designer.cs doesn't get created.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried repairing (and even reinstalling) Visual Studio? I'd also recommend running memtest on your system too.

Comment: Should this be on superuser? Hard to see any programming here.

Comment: Do you have VS2008 SP1 installed?  Maybe that can help.  Also, do you have any VS add-ons installed?  Try uninstalling those.

Comment: @David - it's about a program only used by developers so is on topic. However it's already been cross posted on Super User - http://superuser.com/questions/256353/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot

Comment: @ChrisF Not much point moving it there then, it would only closed as a duplicate!!  ;-)

Comment: Reinstall - too much effort ( for the administrators )], I'll give the memory test a whirl once the admin person sends me a copy of the cd for it, I have SP1 installed without the add ons

Comment: Sometimes SO questions give some insight into the working conditions of other programmers.  It isn't always pretty, one wonders how they ever get anything done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard error message for an access violation (crash), I have seen it in Visual Studio a lot but usually when **my** code crashes. Probably some C++ code in Visual Studio is not handling an error gracefully. I don't know what causes the error, or how to debug Visual Studio.... probably a reinstall of VS is needed, or there is something unusual in your particular machine.